# How to use a variable in a callback function that is not available when the function is created

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I am learning about functional programming in Javascript and I am running into an error on the below code. The error says that `list` is undefined. This is obviously coming from my filterVideos function because it uses list, but list has not yet been defined. I know I can just place the function into my return statement, but I am trying to keep the function separate from the return statement. So my question is, is there a way for me to declare the function before the list variable has been defined?

```
var myFunction = function() {
    var lists = [
            {
                "id": 5434364,
                "name": "New Releases"
            },
            {
                "id": 65456475,
                name: "Thrillers"
            }
        ],
        videos = [
            {
                "listId": 5434364,
                "id": 65432445,
                "title": "The Chamber"
            },
            {
                "listId": 5434364,
                "id": 675465,
                "title": "Fracture"
            },
            {
                "listId": 65456475,
                "id": 70111470,
                "title": "Die Hard"
            },
            {
                "listId": 65456475,
                "id": 654356453,
                "title": "Bad Boys"
            }
        ];

    var filterVideos = function(video){ return video.listId == list.id;};
    var mapVideos = function(video){return {id: video.id, title: video.title};};

    return lists.map(function(list) {
        return {
          name: list.name,
          videos: videos.filter(filterVideos).map(mapVideos)
        };
    });
}

myFunction();
```

Comment: Can you add `list` as a second parameter to the function?

Comment: Your array is called `lists`.  There is no variable called `list` inside `myFunction`.

Your `return` statement calls `lists.map`, and its callback has a parameter called `list`.  This is used *only* inside the callback to refer to the element currently being worked on by `.map()`.

Your `filterVideos` function has no idea what `list` is because it isn't *inside* the `.map().`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change filterVideos so it generates a filtering function that has the list in scope:

```
var myFunction = function() {
    var lists = [{
            "id": 5434364,
            "name": "New Releases"
        }, {
            "id": 65456475,
            name: "Thrillers"
        }],
        videos = [{
            "listId": 5434364,
            "id": 65432445,
            "title": "The Chamber"
        }, {
            "listId": 5434364,
            "id": 675465,
            "title": "Fracture"
        }, {
            "listId": 65456475,
            "id": 70111470,
            "title": "Die Hard"
        }, {
            "listId": 65456475,
            "id": 654356453,
            "title": "Bad Boys"
        }];

    var filterVideos = function(list) {
        return function(video) {
            return video.listId == list.id;
        };
    };
    var mapVideos = function(video) {
        return {
            id: video.id,
            title: video.title
        };
    };

    return lists.map(function(list) {
        return {
            name: list.name,
            videos: videos.filter(filterVideos(list)).map(mapVideos)
        };
    });
}

myFunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

As you say, the error is because list isn't defined at that point in the code. The two obvious solutions are either to either move it into a scope where it is defined (which you say you don't want to do), or pass it as a parameter to the filterVideos function so that it's available within.

Since you can't change the parameters that filter passes to its callback, the most obvious solution is to create a closure which defines the parameter and returns a function that has "list" in scope.

```
var filterVideos = function(list) {
    return function(video) {
        return video.listId == list.id;
    }
};
var mapVideos = function(video){
    return {id: video.id, title: video.title};
};

return lists.map(function(list) {
    return {
      name: list.name,
      videos: videos.filter(filterVideos(list)).map(mapVideos)
    };
});
```